# eclipse-che workspace wont recognize new maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse-che

Tried searching about this but found nothing that could help me and so here i am...

I like the concept of Eclipse on the cloud and started giving it a try with the first basic hello world example. I created the first workspace with java-maven stack with the given console-java-simple project. I was able to run the app, debug it and what not... Next i added a simple maven dependency like apache-commons-math3 to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and initiated the maven build, all good here... was able to see the jar imported to the m2 repo. When i try to import something, the editor doesn't seem to recognize the dependency. It complaints with the following

```
The import org.apache cannot be resolvedJava(268435846)
```

I ignored this error in the editor and initiated the maven build, but java compiler had the same issue and the build failed.

So am i missing something that's so obvious that everybody else is able to figure out :-)

Side Note: I was able to import this same dependency in a java-springboot-msql worksapce without any problem by following the same exact steps.....

Answer (score 0):

If `build.gradle` file exists then `Grandle` is used as build-automation system.

Comment: both gradle and maven build file exits... i haven't really tried updating gradle to see if the dependency gets updated as maven is my primary build tool and i would like to stick to it.